# trying to install and run C++ test code in vs code

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, terminal, mingw-w64

Hi guys i installed the vs code and downloaded the needed extensions (C/C++-code runner)
and i installed Mingw
but when i run this test code

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << "Hello World!";
  return 0;
}
```

it shows this

```
PS C:\Users\faroo\Desktop\C++ 101> cd "c:\Users\faroo\Desktop\C++ 101\" ; if ($?) { g++ calssCar.cpp -o calssCar } ; if ($?) { .\calssCar }
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o): in function `main':
C:/_/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crt0_c.c:18: undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can you please help me

Comment: You forgot to hit Ctrl+S to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is working fine but the linker trying to link it as a Windows GUI App, which uses `WinMain()` instead of `main()` as entry point of application.

You should recheck your compiler flags in vsCode settings. If I remember properly, for Mingw-w64, the flag is `-mwindows`.

I suspect you probably used some template to create vscode project but chose the wrong one (gui app instead of console app)

Also, as a beginner I would recommend using TDM-GCC instead of msys2, as it's better intergreted with Windows and is easier to work with.

Comment: MinGW (at least the one I use) accepts both `main` and `WinMain` regardless of `-mwindows`. And if I forget them, it always complains about `WinMain`, not `main`. *"recommend using TDM-GCC instead of msys2"* MSYS2 should be just fine. A package manager and a linux-like build environment are useful.

Comment: "should" be fine but its not, msys2 version of mingw is broken. i also faced a similar issue, the compiler was insisting on using WinMain() even though i was compiling a shared library. with TDM-GCC, it compiled fine.

Comment: Interesting. I've used it for years without problems, and never heard of anyone having this problem. Consider filing a bug [here](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages) or [here](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages) (depending on which compiler package you used) and/or asking a question here on SO about it (I'd look at it).

Comment: Even with a hello World, it compiles sucessfully, but running the exe gives error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)"

Comment: It works on my end. If you make a question here on SO, and provide all information, I can help you debug it.

Comment: My guess is that you didn't add MSYS2 compiler to the PATH, or have incompatible DLLs in the path prior to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. one thing i noticed is **IF YOU RUN YOUR CODE WITHOUT SAVING** it is giving this error.

try RUN **after saving**

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you create a new cpp file with another title.Then copy your code to the new file.Try to run the code in the new file again.Maybe it  can works.
Such error usually happen to my laptop.It dosen't matter.

Answer (score -1):

It's because maybe you haven't set your path of Mingw. Let me guide you to do that if you're using Windows:

1. Install Mingw (which you already have), like I have installed it in C:\Mingw
2. Then open Mingw\bin folder from that drive, like I have opened C:\MinGW\bin
3. Copy "C:\MinGW\bin" and then open This Pc.
4. Right-click on open space and click properties.
5. Go to Advanced system settings.
6. Click on the Environment variable.
7. Then in system variables, double click on PATH.
8. Click on new, and paste your path there.
9. Press ok and now run your code again in Vscode, it'll surely work!

Comment: No, compiler is clearly being detected and compilation is successful too, but the linker is looking for WinMain entry point instead of main() because of wrong flags probably